# How exchange json between Unity and .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: unity-game-engine, json-deserialization, asp.net-core-3.1, net-standard-2.1

Hello i am developing a `Unity` application that will use a `.NET Core 3.1` `API` .I have my models in a separate `.net standard 2.0` `dll` .I  would have chosen `2.1` to use the `JsonSerializer` class  but it is not supported by `Unity` yet.

My question is:
How does one serialize and deserializes data between the two applications.
If i `Serialize` using the `Newtonsoft.Json` how would that go on the other end while deserializing with the `JsonUtility.FromJson<T>` ?

Is there a conversion available between the two ?
Is there a conversion between `Unity` and `JsonSerializer`?

Is there any way i could share   a .Net Standard 2.1 dll between the two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `System.Text.Json` isn't dependent on .NET Standard 2.1, only 2.0. As such, you can simply add the NuGet to your .NET Standard 2.0 class library. Additionally, while it's preferred to use `System.Text.Json`, you can still opt to continue to use `Newtonsoft.Json` if you prefer in ASP.NET Core 3.1+.

Second, the end result of either library is just JSON, so either library can read what the other library created. The only potential difference would be in how they might serialize, i.e. camel-case vs. pascal-case, custom value converters, etc. However, all of that is configurable in both libraries, so you just need to ensure that the way one is serializing is also the way the other is deserializing.

Comment: I want to use `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: Did you manage to use it? I downloaded the .NET 4.X System.Text.Json NuGet package and copied all dlls from the package to my Unity Plugin folder, it seems to work just fine in the editor, but it doesn't work in WebGL build, it doesn't crash or output any errors, but the deserialize method returns an "empty" object (I creates the correct type instance, but it doesn't fill any properties), but the same method call works in the editor. Kinda hard to debug / find the problem, since the web console doesn't show any error at all.

Comment: *"you can simply add the NuGet to your .NET Standard 2.0 class library"* No, you can't. You seem to be unfamiliar with Unity. The NuGet package manager doesn't translate to Unity the way you expect. There are hoops one needs to jump thru to properly implement System.Text.Json into Unity.